# SQL syntax. Update after inner join

Tags: mysql, syntax, inner-join

```
UPDATE 
     t1 
SET 
     t1.name=t2.name, t1.fb_id=t2.fb_id
FROM 
     nullemail t1
     INNER JOIN run1 t2
         ON t1.email=t2.email;
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this syntax? I have 2 tables. nullemail and run1. I want to update nullemail's columns(`fb_id` and `name`) when the email id in nullemail is the same as run1.

Comment: so what error are you getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE nullemail t1, run1 t2  SET t1.name=t2.name, t1.fb_id=t2.fb_id
where t1.email=t2.email;
```

Try this