# Using a joined column in a where condition

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables.The table `class_students` is related to the `students` table as it gets the `student_id_column` data from there.The `examination_data` has a column (`class_student_id_column`) that gets its data from the `class_students` table `student_id_column` column.

1. `students`

> student_id | student_names
>
> 1...........................ed
>
> 2..........................bravo
>
> 3.........................some name

1. `class_students`

> class_students_id | student_id_column | class_year
>
> 1...................................2..............................2000
>
> 2...................................3..............................2000

1. `examination_data`

examination_data_id | class_students_id_column | php | jquery | drawing

1.........................................1.................................90.....68............      89
1.........................................2.................................64.....89............      99

I want to update the table `examination_data` and to do that for a row ,i want my where statement to point to the `student_id` column.

To do that,i am trying this

```
SELECT
  examination_data.examination_data_id,
  examination_data.class_students_id_column,
  class_students.student_id_column,
  students.student_id,
  examination_data.php,
  examination_data.jquery,
  examination_data.drawing

FROM
  examination_data
  LEFT JOIN class_students ON (examination_data.class_students_id_column=class_students.class_students_id)
  LEFT JOIN students ON (students.student_id=class_students.student_id_column)

  UPDATE  examination_data  SET examination_data.jquery = 96 WHERE students.student_id = 2;
```

My update statement fails because there is no `students.student_id` column in the table `examination_data`.My other try is

```
  UPDATE  examination_data  SET examination_data.jquery = l FROM students INNER JOIN ON students.student_id=... WHERE students.student_id = 2;
```

but that hit a brick wall hard.

Is this even possible or will i have to have  another `student_id_column` in the `examination_data` table?.

Comment: [Refer This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802921/sql-syntax-update-after-inner-join/17803044#17803044), this is similar to what you asked for

Comment: Thanks Akhil,i shall have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sub query:

```
UPDATE
  examination_data
SET
  jquery = 96
WHERE
  class_students_id_column = (
    SELECT class_students_id FROM class_students WHERE student_id_column = 2
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
UPDATE  examination_data  SET examination_data.jquery = 96 WHERE
examination_data.class_students_id_column =(
SELECT class_students_id FROM class_students WHERE student_id_column = 2);
```